# How to export the resources based on pricing tier in Azure Subscription level?

Tags: azure, azureportal

**For the Function Apps, we have pricing tier grouping**

[image]

**For the APIM Services, we have pricing tier with the Group By Tier view**:

[image]

Service Wise - I can list the Pricing based using Grouping Column but how to list the resources with Pricing Tier based in the Subscription level resources - I cannot see any option "Grouping by pricing tier/tier/plan" in the grouping drop down?

I tried Googling whether it is possible with Azure PowerShell or CLI, but no luck.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, its not possible to group the resources by pricing tier at subscription level as the resources have different pricing tiers and some resources don't have pricing tiers at all.

[image]

For example, VMs will not have pricing tier or model but pricing is based on many factors such as Region, Image, Size, etc.

Reference: MS Q&A [1303235](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1303235/how-to-export-the-resources-based-on-pricing-tier)